# Bind ion-content as scroller of GSAP Timeline

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, gsap, scrolltrigger

I am implementing GSAP in an Ionic application (v 6.18.1).

I cannot create a ScrollTrigger that identifies the ion-content component as a scroller.

I found a workaround that carries some glitches due to the fact that the start and end parameters set to 'center' move by scrolling and return to center when not scrolling so with **pin:true** (and i need it) there is an obvious glitch.

Here the code of my component:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    gsap.utils.toArray('.section').forEach((r) => {
      this.scaleFrom0(r);
    });
  }
  
    scaleFrom0(trigger) {
    const animation = timeline()
  
      .from(trigger, {
        scale: 0,
      })
      .to(trigger, {
        scale: 2,
      })

    return ScrollTrigger.create({
      animation,
      trigger,
      scroller: '.content-scroll',
      scrub: 2,
      snap: 1 / 2,
      pin: true,
      pinSpacing: true,
      start: `top center`,
      end: '+=1000px center',
      markers: true,
    });
  }
```

```css
.content-scroll {
  position: absolute;
  // border: solid 1px red;
  // margin: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  // background: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <div class="content-scroll">
    <div class="presenter">
      <strong>TITLE</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <app-section></app-section>
    </div>
 
    <div class="section">
      <app-section></app-section>
    </div>
 
    <div class="section">
      <app-section></app-section>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
      <app-section></app-section>
    </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

I want to delete the div.content-scroll and bind ion-content as scroller into ScrollTrigger.create() **or SOMETHING FOR TO STOP GLITCHES!!**

I tried:
scroller: document.querySelector('ion-content')
ion-content class=".content-scroll"

But I dont see markers anymore...

How can I stop the markers when i'm scrolling?

Some tips?

Thanks to everybody in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution talking on GSAP forum.

It's an overflow problem.

Solved here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wxueqy?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts